# How to make a dll delayed depends on another dll?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

when building a dll, how to make an dll delayed depend on another dll? Do I need to set up anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the [/DELAYLOAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) linker option, followed by the names of the delay-loaded DLLs.

Note that a DLL delay-loading other DLLs should not call any delay-loaded functions from `DllMain()`.

See [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) for more details.